# Show dialog inside gridview

Tags: android, image, gridview, dialog

I've implemented a gridview of images that are picked from sdcard.Now i want every image to be shown in dialog on click.How to do it within Image Adapter?Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: make your custom dialog with imageview.then on click listener get the image url from your arrylist and set on ImageView.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer).  That does two things.  It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't do that in your adapter...  Do it inside your click listener (from wherever you call and set the gridview adapter).

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
       ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageviewid);  // get the resource id
       Drawable image = iv.getDrawable();  // get the image
       CreateYourDialog(image);            // pass the image to a method to create your dialog
    }
});
```

If your GridView is only the imageview for each cell, then you can skip the `findViewById` line of code and simply use `Drawable image = v.getDrawable();`.